# Two Radio Button category

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gender

```
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'>Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='kid'>Kid
```

Brand

```
<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand1'>Brand1
<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand2'>Brand2
<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand3'>Brand3

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.chkbox').on('change', function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var url = 'url.php?' + $(this).val();
  console.log(url);

  window.location = url;
}
});
});
</script>
```

I want the url to be like url.php?brand=$brand&&gender=$gender
plz help

Comment: What and where's `.chkbox'?

Comment: I heard that there is more than two genders, but never that `kid` is one of them.

Comment: Sorry for that... .chkbox is the class for the radio tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var url = 'url.php?';
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index, obj) {
      if (obj.checked)
        url += obj.name + '=' + obj.value + '&';
    });

    url = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('&'));

    console.log(url);

    //window.location = url;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'>Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='kid'>Kid

<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand1'>Brand1
<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand2'>Brand2
<input type='radio' name='brand' value='brand3'>Brand3
```